# Why Status Bar is not showing for component screen after relaunching app in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Why Status Bar is not showing for component screen after relaunching app which was closed by pressing the back button in react-native

First time launching the app:

[image]

Second time launching the app after closing first launched app:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting StatusBar Hidden to false in every screen works for me.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    StatusBar.setHidden(false, 'fade');
  }, []);
```